# Where are the $U(1)$ topological gauge theory zero modes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, seiberg-witten-theory

In [this 1995 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505186), Witten claims the following:

> The zero modes (i.e. of the gauge field) do not give factors of $\Im \tau$; they are tangent to the space of classical minima, which is a torus of dimension $b_1(X)$ and has a volume independent of $\Im \tau$.

The idea is that the photon partition function for an abelian gauge theory in a curved compact manifold $X$ includes an integration over the $b_1$ zero modes of flat connections. A flat connection $A$ is one such that its curvature vanishes. Also, for the following questions to make sense we have to assume that $b_1 > 0$, i.e. the fundamental group of $X$ is not trivial.

**Why these zero modes span a torus $T^{b_1}=H^2(X,\mathbb{R})/H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$?**

The latter is found [in a paper by Marino and Moore](http://cds.cern.ch/record/352306/files/9804104.pdf) (page 2). **These zero modes live on $T^{b_1}$ or in its tangent space as this paper says?**

And most importantly these zero modes are the zero modes of some Laplace operator. **What is this Laplace operator then?**

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505186 & http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9804104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laplace operator is just the general [Laplace-deRham operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Laplace.E2.80.93de_Rham_operator) $\Delta = \mathrm{d}\delta + \delta \mathrm{d}$, for $\mathrm{d}$ the exterior derivative and $\delta$ the codifferential. Forms $\omega$ with $\Delta \omega = 0$ are called *harmonic forms* and by Hodge's theorem, the space of harmonic $p$-forms is isomorphic to the $p$-th deRham cohomology, therefore the number of harmonic 1-forms (which is what Witten means by "possible zero modes of $A$") is the dimension of the first cohomology, which, for real coefficients, is the dual of first homology and therefore has dimension $b_1$. Note that it is crucial for this correspondence that the gauge group is $\mathrm{U}(1)$, since then $A$ is just a $\mathbb{R}$-valued form.

The flat connections have $\mathrm{d}A = F = 0$ and are therefore closed forms. The gauge symmetry corresponds exactly to quotienting out exact 1-forms, so the space of gauge equivalence classes of flat connections is $H^1(X,\mathbb{R})$. The harmonic forms span this vector space, and quotienting out $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ makes this into a torus-like space which still has the original vector space as tangent space at every point, hence the tangent space is spanned by the zero modes/harmonic forms.

I suspect that the quotient by $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ on the space of classical minima is related to the $\theta$-symmetry of the action, but I don't actually know much Seiberg-Witten theory, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know already what you nicely say in the first two paragraphs this is why I said that indeed the total number of zero modes are $b_1$. $X$ being a 4-manifold makes dimensions of $i$-th homology and cohomology equal. Also, I suspect that since the gauge field can be interpreted as a 1-form and integrated over 1-cycles it is the same as saying that these are the $b_1$ cycles of the $b_1$-dimensional torus. Now, what confuses me is the statement that the zero-modes span the space tangent $T$. Do they consider this torus as submanifold in X?

Comment: @Marion No, the torus is not a submanifold of anything. But it *is* a quotient of the space of harmonic forms $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$ by a discrete lattice, and you should be able to convince yourself that the quotient of a vector space by a lattice still has the original vector space as its tangent space at every point.